# How can I linkify URLs which appear in plain text?

Tags: java, html

How can I linkify URLs which appear in plain text? For example,

> Today i want to share a link: www.google.com

I would like to make "www.google.com" clickable by putting `<a>` tags around. Do I have to detect URLs and links with Java string parsing facilities and put `<a>` tags around them?

Comment: `...do i have to detect urls and links with Java String parsing facilities and put <a> tags arround them?` In my opinion, yes. You could probably do a regexp for it, but it is not as trivial as it sounds first...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the regexp from [Matthew O'Riordan's page](http://blog.mattheworiordan.com/post/13174566389/url-regular-expression-for-links-with-or-without-the) to match an URL with or even without the protocol part:

```
/((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/.\w-_]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&;%@.\w_]*)#?(?:[.\!\/\\w]*))?)/
```

Comment: thanks, can i use this with java directly? it suitable for java, right? i do not know regex, if it is a standard for every language.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Linkify](https://github.com/HitSend/jQuery-linkify/) which is simple to use, it will surround the link in given selector in plain text to links.